# Excel Inelegant code, help optimising required

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

I have some code that is perfectly functional, but it seems very bloated to me. How can I streamline this code?

```
Sub RowDiv1()

Dim R1 As Range
Dim R2 As Range
Dim R3 As Range
Dim R4 As Range
Dim R5 As Range
Dim R6 As Range
Dim R7 As Range
Dim R8 As Range

    With Worksheets("Working Sheet 1")
        Set R1 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("AH6000").End(xlUp))
        With R1
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

        Set R2 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("AD6000").End(xlUp))
        With R2
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

        Set R3 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("Z6000").End(xlUp))
        With R3
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

        Set R4 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("V6000").End(xlUp))
        With R4
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

        Set R5 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("R6000").End(xlUp))
        With R5
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

        Set R6 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("N6000").End(xlUp))
        With R6
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

        Set R7 = .Range(.Range("G6000").End(xlUp), .Range("J6000").End(xlUp))
        With R7
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -4).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With

    End With


End Sub
```

As I said, this code works fine, but it just seems very long for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Tell us what your code should do, so we are able tell you an alternative way

Comment: With **working code** that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se].

Comment: You may find some pointers here : http://www.excelitems.com/2010/12/optimize-vba-code-for-faster-macros.html

Comment: What is the significance of row 6000?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie, there is no significance. I chose it as an arbitary number when I started. When I started this I had never gone beyond recording macros, so I was making lots of stupid desicions and mistakes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the heads up. I'll direct questions to the correct place now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just splitting your last row by sets of 4 columns, this should do the same:

```
Sub SplitRowBy4Cols()
    Dim j As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G60000").End(xlUp).Resize(, 28)  ' G:AH last row
        For j = 1 To .Columns.Count Step 4
            .Offset(1 + CLng(j / 4), -4).Resize(, 4).Value = .Cells(1, j).Resize(, 4).Value
        Next
        .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Greater elegance could be achieve by not declaring so many Ranges where all you need is only one to which you assign different collections of cells, one after the other.

As for the rest of your code it is more of a puzzle than a coding task. When the task is to express a thought into code you know the thought. In a puzzle you try to determine the thought from its description, which you have described as wanting improvement. This site is about coding. We don't do puzzles.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, all aspects of coding relate to problem solving, don't they?
I posed the question as the sub is part of a longer process that's got very bulky. I was trying to optimise it. Furthermore, I was trying to improve my coding, which is presently quite poor. Thank you for the "help" though.